# AngularJS: Getting data from service into controller

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

I've read various SO posts about promises and callbacks, but am still confused on when to use which.  I'm not even 100% sure if my problem involves promises or callbacks.  I'm having trouble getting data from a service into a controller, and then accessing that data in the view.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as appCtrl" flex="">
    <div ng-controller="FlexClusterCtrl as modelCtrl">
        <md-grid-list md-cols-sm="1" md-cols-md="2" md-cols-gt-md="6"
                      md-row-height-gt-md="1:1" md-row-height="4:3" md-gutter="8px"
                      md-gutter-gt-sm="4px" class="gridList">
            <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="cluster in instances.clusters"
                          md-rowspan="1" md-colspan="3" md-colspan-sm="1" class="gridTile">
                <md-grid-list flex="" md-cols-sm="2" md-cols-md="4" md-cols-gt-md="6"
                              md-row-height-gt-md="1:1" md-row-height="1:1" md-gutter="6px"
                              layout-fill>
                    <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="cluster2 in cluster.clusters2"
                                  md-rowspan="1" md-colspan="1" class="flexTile">
                        <md-grid-list flex="" md-cols-sm="1" md-cols-md="2" md-cols-gt-md="3"
                                      md-row-height="4:3" layout-fill>
                            <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="INSTANCE in cluster2.INSTANCES"
                                          md-colspan="1" class="instanceTile">
                                <md-button ng-disabled>{{INSTANCE.ID}}</md-button>
                            </md-grid-tile>
                        </md-grid-list>
                    </md-grid-tile>
                </md-grid-list>
                <md-grid-tile-footer style="text-align:center;"><h3>{{cluster.name}}</h3></md-grid-tile-footer>
            </md-grid-tile>
        </md-grid-list>
    </div>
</div>
```

**controller and service**

```
angular.module('app')
    .service('ModelSvc', ['$http', function($http) {
        return {
            getInstances: function() {
                $http.get('vendor/resources/flat.json')
                    .then(function(res) {
                        $instances = res.data;
                        return $instances;
                    });
            }
        };
    }])

    .controller('FlexClusterCtrl', ['$scope', 'ModelSvc', function($scope, ModelSvc) {
        $scope.init = function() {
            ModelSvc.getInstances().then(function(data) {
                $scope.instances = data;
            });
        };
    }]);
```

I'm using Angular Material if the HTML looks funky to some of you.  I've also tried using [in my first ngRepeat] `ng-repeat="cluster in init.instances.clusters"` and `ng-repeat="cluster in init.clusters"`, but to no avail.  I don't know if the problem is in my service, controller, or view.  The browser is not returning any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the promise, and then you can put the data in scope

```
  getInstances: function() {
                return $http.get('vendor/resources/flat.json');
                }
```

One other thin, it gives you no error's, because your promise don't have an error callback, like this:

```
promise.then(
      function(data) { 
          //something
      },
      function(error) {
          // error calback
      });
```

Comment: Hmm ok. Then I would get that data in the view with what? `ng-repeat="cluster in init.clusters`?  I've tried a few combinations with your suggestion but none of them are working.

Comment: You're storing it in $scope.instances not $scope.init. So maybe ng-repeat="instance in instances".
Have you checked if $scope.instances get's your data?

Comment: Looking at your HTML, it looks fine, so I think is a problem with receiving your data.

Comment: The data it's getting is the response header or something... `{data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}` after I run `console.log($scope.instances)`.

Comment: I got it worked out.  I'll just add a little to your answer.

Comment: Just change $scope.instance = data to $scope.instance = data.data, maybe you can change your argument to res then do res.data. 
Glad I could help.